# Отучиваться или отучаться?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Отучиваешься или отучаешься — как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

В словаре указаны  **обе формы**:

**ОТУЧИТЬСЯ**, св. 1. Заставить себя отвыкнуть от чего-л. Надо о. от некоторых манер. 2. Перестать учиться, окончить своё учение. // Кончить учиться, заниматься. Первоклашки уже отучились. **Отучаться**,  нсв. **Отучиваться.**

**Однако частотность глагола "отучаться" знчительно выше:**

А Декарт предупреждает, что нужно **отучаться** от привычки мыслить наглядно. [Мераб Мамардашвили. Картезианские размышления (1981-1993)]

И за два месяца мы очень быстро **отучились** говорить слово «нет». [Екатерина Белоусова, Анастасия Матвеева. Живая обертка // «Эксперт», 2014]

Все **отучились** в школе-интернате для коренных народов, но потом решили вернуться в тундру. [Никита Аронов. Детсад на оленьем ходу // «Огонек», 2015]